# Why doesn't Bootstrap modal show without invoking javascript code

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I created an `html` page with `bootstrap`'s `modal` code (copied from `Bootstrap`'s website. I notice that the `modal` doesn't show unless I call `modal('show')`. Why? Shouldn't the browser interpret the html and display the `modal` box? The following code doesn't show the `modal` but if you comment the `script` at the end, it will show the `modal`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <base href=""> 
  <title>Example</title>
  <!--meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'"-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="fiddle.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="fiddle.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>  
  Did you see the dialog box?
  <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="mydialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<¬- UNCOMMENT THIS AND THE MODAL WILL SHOW-->
<!--script>
$('#mydialog').modal('show');    
  </script-->

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap modal is designed for trigger the modal window when you `click` on the element(i.e. a button or a link) with following attributes:
data-toggle="modal" opens the modal window
data-target="#myModal" points to the id of the modal

In your code, no click event occurs and thus modal was not open bydefault

It looks like you want to open modal when page load as the modal is not designed to open on page load you have to manually trigger modal's `show` Method

Comment: Well explained. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i think it was happen because in  head tag you join jquery and bootstrap  librrary so your don’t need you code anymore because bootstrap do this for you..

Answer (score 0):

since modal works if you clicked on a button to toggle display
this example works fine 
  see this link https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#live-demo

Answer (score 0):

You can Use this bootstrap modal code this is working fine.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Button to Open the Modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Open modal
  </button>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div class="modal" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
      
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
          Modal body..
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because modal`div` with the class of `modal` has a display property set to `none` by default.

Comment the script and inspect the modal in your browser you will notice that it has a `display` of `none`.

When you call `.modal()` and pass in the parameter `show` on your *modal id*, then it's `display` property gets set to `block`, which is when you are able to see it.

This is because modals are not supposed to be shown by default but instead on a user event so you can call `.modal('show`)` on the event.

```js
$('#mydialog').modal('show');
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
<body>  
  Did you see the dialog box?
  <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="mydialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```